# Using Flask to send form data to a database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I've created a simple web page with a text field and a button. I want my application to update a record in my database with the content of the text field when I click the button. Seems simple enough, but I can't figure out what I'm missing. Here's my code thus far:

**app.py sample**

```
@app.route('/update-audit/', methods=['POST'])
def update_audit(test_name, description):
    cur = connect_db()
    cur.execute('UPDATE audit SET description = ? WHERE test_name = ?', (description, test_name,))
    return render_template('clicked.html')
```

**audit.html sample**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('update_audit') }}" method="post">
    <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="desc" value="{{ row[3] }}" size="140">
        <input type="hidden" name="update_audit" value="{{ row[2] }}, desc"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update"/>
    </td>
</form>
```

**clicked.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<body>
{{ form.description }}<br />
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

**table sample**

```
id | tool name | test name | description
========================================
1  | "tool1"   | "test1"   | "update me!"
```

Not sure if I'm missing an essential concept (I played around with flask_wtf and didn't get anywhere) or if I'm a step or two away from making this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Set a name attribute for text input so that it gets sent with the submitted form.

```
<input name="description" type="text" id="desc" value="{{ row[3] }}" size="140">
```

Update your view function to get description from the POST dictionary attribute of `request`. `test_name` also needs to be updated to an appropriate value.

```
@app.route('/update-audit/', methods=['POST'])
def update_audit():
    description = request.form.get('description')
    test_name = request.form.get('update_audit')
    cur = connect_db()
    with cur:
        cur.execute(
            'UPDATE audit SET description = ? '
            'WHERE test_name = ?;', (description, test_name,))

    # commit changes to the database
    return render_template('clicked.html')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I'm getting this traceback: AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'POST'

Comment: Also, I'll need to get the test name passed into update_audit so that the database knows which row I want to update. This should happen in audit.html, and row[2] contains the test name.

Comment: It should be `request.form` not `request.POST`

Comment: That got the data sent to the clicked.html view, but the database still isn't updated. Close though!

Comment: Yes, you need to commit changes to the db.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

**app.py sample**

```
@app.route('/update-audit/', methods=['POST'])
def update_audit():
    description = request.form.get('description')
    test_name = request.form.get('test_name')

    sql = 'UPDATE audit SET description=? WHERE test_name=?'
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql, (description, test_name))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    return render_template('clicked.html', data=(test_name, description))
```

**audit.html sample**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('update_audit') }}" method="POST">
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="test_name" value="{{ row[2] }}">{{ row[2] }}</input>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="desc" value="{{ row[3] }}" size="100" maxlength="140"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update"/>
    </td>
</form>
</tr>
```

The answer is a combination of the right SQL-Alchemy commands, and ensuring that I'm sending the data to the update_audit function via two input-tags in audit.html.

Answer (score 0):

Your render_template should get a form argument:

return render_template('clicked.html', form=form)

It is also not clear in the code you provided where the Forms are treated in python and where the variable row comes from.

Comment: row is the current index of the iter data from the database. When I load audit.html, I pass along the result of a query which asks for all the data in the table sample.